# How to Add custom animated image on page when ajax function is executing in the background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using a javascript file for adding an animated image on a page whenever there is some ajaxStart() method is going on and remove it when ajaxStop() happens. How to do it using javascript or jQuery? I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
   $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Which version of jQuery lib are you using ?

Comment: Use this : `beforeSend: function(){//your loading image..}`

Comment: The events works fine, but are you expecting that the cursor will change, and did you test that with just CSS to see if the cursor does in fact change ?

Comment: @Java_User: well if there are multiple ajax requests from different part of the code, then it has to be added for each of the ajax call instance. this wont work in that case.

Comment: @dreamweiver : The question is what is the error (if any). This is one of the way I showed.

Comment: @Java_User:well one would always use `.ajaxStart()` & `.ajaxStop` only when a common implementations is required. trying your way will also work but would be a over kill, if a generic action is required for all ajax calls

Comment: @dreamweiver :It was just an example

Answer (score 0):

try this..

css:

```
 .ajaxLoader {
     background-image: url('http://www.bet4win.it/images/img_stats/ajax-loader-large.gif');
   width:500px !important;
   height:500px !important;
   position:absolute;
   top:50px;
   left: 50px;
 }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
    $('body').append('<div class="ajaxLoader"> </div>');
    $('body').css('cursor', 'wait');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
   $('body .ajaxLoader').remove();
   $('body').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

Comment: Hi JF it I found that if I am adding alert code when I initiate any ajax call in my script file, it comes up. But that css thing is not working.Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Hi JF it  Thanks for your quick response.But no luck..I tried with that code too.but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Chiranjit how bout now? (changed only css);

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps ..

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 

  // Setup the ajax indicator
  $('body').append('<div id="ajaxBusy"><p><img src="images/loading.gif"></p></div>');

  $('#ajaxBusy').css({
    display:"none",
    margin:"0px",
    paddingLeft:"0px",
    paddingRight:"0px",
    paddingTop:"0px",
    paddingBottom:"0px",
    position:"absolute",
    right:"3px",
    top:"3px",
     width:"auto"
  });
});

// Ajax activity indicator bound to ajax start/stop document events
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').show(); 
}).ajaxStop(function(){ 
  $('#ajaxBusy').hide();
});
```

[Demo Link](http://skfox.com/jqExamples/AjaxActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check this first

**Article from jQuery Official site:**

*"If `$.ajax()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` is called with the `global option` set to `false`, the `.ajaxStart()` method will not fire. "*

Answer (score 0):

Setting `$('body').css('cursor', 'wait');` doesn't really work, you should be setting that style on the `html` element

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
   $('html').css('cursor', 'wait');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
   $('html').css('cursor', 'auto');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gk2MD/1/)

Other working options would be

```
$(document.documentElement).css('cursor', 'wait');
$('*').css('cursor', 'wait');
```

etc... but `$('html')` seems the most appropiate.